# When merging PDF documents using iText, the image fields are missing

Tags: image, pdf, merge, static, itext

I had a PDF document and needed to add a couple of image fields. I imported the pdf file into Adobe LiveCycle as artwork. I then added my 2 images and saved as a static file. When I view the file using Adobe Reader, I can see the images. But when I try to merge the file with other static and dynamic pdf files created using LiveCycle, the images are missing.

I looked at the following thread 
[Images (imageField) are not shown after iText PDF Merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615232/images-imagefield-are-not-shown-after-itext-pdf-merging)

but after checking the solution shown there against my code, I am already using PdfCopy instead of PdfWriter:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baosList.get(0).toByteArray());
        Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        reader.close();

        PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, output);
        document.open();

        for (ByteArrayOutputStream baos : baosList)
        {
            // copy content
            reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());

            for (int idx = 1; idx <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); idx++)
                writer.addPage(writer.getImportedPage(reader, idx));

            reader.close();
            baos.close();
        }
```

I have other dynamic PDF files with images that are fine. I wonder if my problem is because I imported the original file as artwork.

Comment: Why you cannot do just `writer.addDocument(reader);` instead of page loop? Check [this example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/adding-cover-page-existing-pdf). Your approach via `writer.getImportedPage(...)` is exactly how one [**should not** do it](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents-itext5/how-not-merge-documents).